# JQuery Grid (jqGrid) with Material Design

Tags: datagrid, jqgrid, material-design

jqGrid is a great data grid component, it has good support to integrate with Twitter Bootstrap, anyone here come across or know how to make jqGrid to fit in the material design framework such as Material Design Lite?

Hope to hear from you soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While not perfect, there is a bootstrap version of mdl [here](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

Beyond that, you could just include both frameworks and piece them together yourself.

Comment: Thanks for writing. I did aware about this solution, just to find out is there any alternative solutions which is short path and lesser effort.